# WPF Correct use of BitmapScalingMode for BitmapImages

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm trying to increase the texture quality in WPF.  What I've read says the preferred method is to set it for each image separately:

```
RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(myImage, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality)
```

I've tried this for BitmapImages, ImageBrushes and DiffuseMaterials but this doesn't seem to do anything.

What has worked is this:

```
VisualBitmapScalingMode = VisualBitmapScalingMode.HighQuality
```

Which throws the following warning:

> "Warning  BC42025 Access of shared member, constant member, enum member
> or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be
> evaluated."

If this won't cause any issues (I haven't noticed any) then I can live with that, but is there a correct way to handle this?  Where should I declare "VisualBitmapScalingMode = VisualBitmapScalingMode.HighQuality"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode applies to a UIElement which an Image is but a BitmapImage isn't.

The correct way is to set it for the parent UIElement, i.e.:

```
RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(MainGrid, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality)
```

I guess the UIElements must inherit their properties from the Visual class which would explain why overriding the Visual class changed the quality of all UIElements on the form.

Answer (score 0):

> Where should I declare "VisualBitmapScalingMode = VisualBitmapScalingMode.HighQuality"?

The `VisualBitmapScalingMode` property is `internal` to the `Visual`.

You can set it in a custom class that inherits from a `Visual`, e.g.:

```
public class SharpImage : System.Windows.Controls.Image
{
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        VisualBitmapScalingMode = BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality;
        base.OnRender(dc);
    }
}
```

You then use your custom class instead of the built-in type, e.g.:

```
<local:SharpImage Source=... />
```

Comment: I don't have any objects of type Visual, but setting "VisualBitmapScalingMode = VisualBitmapScalingMode.HighQuality" affects all textures of type BitmapImage, ImageBrush and DiffuseMaterial.  None of those have a quality property.

Comment: What do you mean by "affects all textures"? The property is a member of the `Visual` type.  Where else do you think you can set it...?